# How to remove line breaks in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```html
<p>
    First line of output.<br\>
    This is the second line.<br\>
</p>
```

With `bs.find('p').text` I'm getting this output:

```
    First line of output.
    This is the second line.
```

I want to remove <br> tags and I want to get an output like `First line of output. This is the second line.`
I tried replacing `\n`, `\r\n` with a space but nothing has changed. How can I solve it?

Comment: *How* did you "tried replacing \n, \r\n with a space"?

Comment: @ScottHunter bs.find('p').text.replace('\n', ' ')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply run "replace" on the string.

```
s = "<p>First line of output.<br\>This is the second line.<br\></p>"
s.replace("<br\>", "")
```

will delete all tags "<br>" and then run replace("\n", "") on the same string